# Unable to kill a process in SQL Server with sys.syprocesses having waitresource = MSDASQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a process stuck in "KILLED/ROLLBACK" stage.
The waitresource for this is MSDASQL.

I was executing the below query:

```
SELECT * into ##temp  
FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL',
                'Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}',
                'select * from C:\MyFolder\File.csv')
```

It's a small CSV file (13kb).

I have executed it previously and it used to complete within few seconds.
But this time it took more than 5 mins, so I killed the session, unfortunately it hasn't been killed and I can still see the process.

I researched a lot about it.
I took the kpid to identify the thread in PowerShell and kill it.
But, unfortunately the PowerShell command has only the option to kill the entire process.(not just the individual thread.)
This is a problem because this thread comes under SQL Server process.

```
Get-CimInstance win32_thread -filter "Handle = 15372"
```

[image]

I cannot restart the SQL instance as it is a production server.

Any ideas, how to terminate this process?

Comment: What's the result of `select status, command, wait_type, percent_complete, blocking_session_id from sys.dm_exec_requests` for that session id? If anything in `blocking_session_id` what is the result for *that* session id?

Comment: This is the result:
`status command wait_type percent_complete blocking_session_id
running KILLED/ROLLBACK OLEDB 0 0`

Comment: Hmm, it really does sound like it's stuck somewhere. There are ways to terminate a single thread https://superuser.com/questions/1073439/how-do-i-kill-a-specific-thread-in-windows but I would strongly advise to wait for a maintenance window and do a graceful restart. No system is so indispensable that it cannot be taken down for 5 minutes, or at least it should not be so.

Comment: You are right, I should wait for a maintenance window for the restart. Its not worth to terminate a single thread. Moreover its not blocking anything, so that's a relief. Thank you so much. @Charlieface